# Bootstrap 5: Hide/Show navbar after scroll 300px

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I want to hide the Bootstrap navbar after scrolling for 300px.

At the moment I'm using the following code ([from here](https://bootstrap-menu.com/detail-autohide.html)).

It works but the navbar hides immediately after scrolling.
I want it to hide after 300px. Is there a way to add that to the script?

**HTML:**

```
<nav class="autohide navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
 <div class="container-fluid">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
   <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#main_nav">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main_nav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"> Menu item </a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"> Menu item </a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"> Menu item </a></li>
    </ul>
  </div> <!-- navbar-collapse.// -->
 </div> <!-- container-fluid.// -->
</nav>
```

**Javascript:**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

  el_autohide = document.querySelector('.autohide');
  
  // add padding-top to bady (if necessary)
  navbar_height = document.querySelector('.navbar').offsetHeight;
  document.body.style.paddingTop = navbar_height + 'px';

  if(el_autohide){
    var last_scroll_top = 0;
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
          let scroll_top = window.scrollY;
         if(scroll_top < last_scroll_top) {
              el_autohide.classList.remove('scrolled-down');
              el_autohide.classList.add('scrolled-up');
          }
          else {
              el_autohide.classList.remove('scrolled-up');
              el_autohide.classList.add('scrolled-down');
          }
          last_scroll_top = scroll_top;
    }); 
    // window.addEventListener
  }
  // if

}); 
// DOMContentLoaded  end
```

**CSS:**

```
.scrolled-down{
  transform:translateY(-100%); transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.scrolled-up{
  transform:translateY(0); transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hello** You can solve this problem by modifying the if conditional(`scroll_top < 300`). In addition to making the nav to fixed position, and giving the main content a margin top the size of the nav so that the content looks good.

The idea is that, analyze the code below for better understanding.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

  el_autohide = document.querySelector('.autohide');
  
  // add padding-top to bady (if necessary)
  //el_autohide.style="position: fix;top:0;"

  if(el_autohide){
    var last_scroll_top = 0;
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
          let scroll_top = window.scrollY;
          //console.log(scroll_top > 300)
         if(scroll_top < 300) {
              el_autohide.classList.remove('scrolled-down');
              el_autohide.classList.add('scrolled-up');
          }
          else {
              el_autohide.classList.remove('scrolled-up');
              el_autohide.classList.add('scrolled-down');
          }
          last_scroll_top = scroll_top;
    }); 
    // window.addEventListener
  }
  // if

}); 
// DOMContentLoaded  end
```

```css
.scrolled-down{
  transform:translateY(-100%); transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.scrolled-up{
  transform:translateY(0); transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.autohide{
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 0;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="autohide navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
 <div class="container-fluid">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
   <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#main_nav">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main_nav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"> Menu item </a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"> Menu item </a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"> Menu item </a></li>
    </ul>
  </div> <!-- navbar-collapse.// -->
 </div> <!-- container-fluid.// -->
</nav>

<p style="margin-top: 100px">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusm dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusm od tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>






















<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusm dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusm od tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```